# Magento 2 after running upgrade command images, css & js deleted

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, upgrade

Whenever I run upgrade command in Magento 2, some of my CSS and JS and Images files deleted automatically, sometimes deleted from third party modules, and sometimes deleted from magento vendor folder.

Please guide me!

Comment: which mode you are using ?

Comment: development mode

Comment: if it developer mode, CSS and JS should automatic created.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about Core files, like from any of my module some css and js deleted automatically and sometimes deleted from vendor folder

Comment: when you run upgrade, you can see the output, it will clean in `generated`, `var`, `pub`. It won't do any thing with file in `vendor` or 3rd modules

Comment: Yes It should happen, but I think there is some third party module in my magento which is forcefully deleting images, css or js while running upgrade command, I will check thankyou for response

Comment: have you tried to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` command ?

Comment: did you checked pub/static folder? is there available .htaccess file?

Comment: @HardikVisa running commands not solved my issue.

Comment: @NareshRupareliya yes `.htaccess` is there.

Comment: somethimes it happened because of wrong permission. can u please set permission to whole project read write and execute and then run command and check.

Comment: @NareshRupareliya I am working on live server can't change permission.
Secondly, I have checked css, js and images files permission is 664

Comment: @temper did you check php `error.log` ?

Comment: @HardikVisa didn't find anything useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the issue in my third party module, after disable the modules, and running commands, my issue was fixed.
The commands which I run after disabling module was:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```